# R# How to keep TABs when autoformatting

Tags: resharper

I'm formatting my code using TABs.
I like Resharper autoformatting option but I wish like R# to keep my TABs in each lines.
I've tried find some cfg option but with no success

Any idea how to achieve that?
If this is not the part of standard maybe you how to write some R# extension to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Resharper, it's Visual Studio's preference.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Keep Tabs.

Comment: Sorry, you are not right. I have this checked actually and R# eats my TABs (when VS doesnt)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have the same problem! Maybe it has something to do with Stylceop for R'. I have it installed. @Maciej : How about you? Did you solve the problem?